# How to represent clock

Tags: datetime, dart, time

Is there a built in way to represent clock in dart or flutter? I only want to represent time in 24 hours clock.

**P.S.** I am currently rolling my own solution because I needed a static, locale insensitive clock which is pretty easy. But I was just looking if there is a way.

**P.P.S** I owned the backend. So I was able to tweak it to return date.

**Old question:** I am getting a time back from an API which I want to parse in my flutter app. I had a look at `DateTime` class but there is no apparent method to parse time as I am not interested in the date. Is there a way to represent only time and parse it in dart? Ex- `20:05:00` which should mean 5 minutes past 8 o'clock.

**P.S** This is my implementation

```dart
extension NumberUtil on int {
  bool isBetween(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    /// Checks if an int is between lower and upper bound both inclusive
    return this >= lowerBound && this <= upperBound;
  }
}

class Time {
  final int hours, minutes, seconds;

  Time(this.hours, this.minutes, this.seconds) {
    assert( hours.isBetween(0, 24) && minutes.isBetween(0, 60) && seconds.isBetween(0, 60) );
  }

  factory Time.parse(String string) {
    /// String should be in 24 hour format: hh:mm:ss. The caller is responsible
    /// for catching the parsing exception because:
    /// 1. It should almost never occur.
    /// 2. Because this is a UI app, the UI is most suited to handle that by
    /// displaying a "something went wrong" dialog

    final temp = string.split(':');

    assert (temp.length == 3);
    return Time(
      int.parse(temp[0]),
      int.parse(temp[1]),
      int.parse(temp[2]),
    );
  }

  int compareTo(Time t) {
    /// Performs a 3 way comparison between the this and t. Returns 0 if the two
    /// objects are same. Returns 1 if this is greater than t. Returns -1 otherwise

    if (this.hours > t.hours) return 1;
    if (this.hours < t.hours) return -1;

    /// at this point hours is same

    if (this.minutes > t.minutes) return 1;
    if (this.minutes < t.minutes) return -1;

    /// At this point minutes are same

    if (this.seconds > t.seconds) return 1;
    if (this.seconds < t.seconds) return -1;

    /// At this point everything is same
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
currentTime = DateTime.now();
targetTime = DateTime.parse('here some times format');

currentTime.difference(targetTime)  or  currentTime.difference(targetTime).inHours // this??
```

or

Do you find this package
https://pub.dev/packages/timeago

Comment: This doesn't work without a date. I don't have a date. I have time in 24 hour clock format. Anyway, I guess I will just roll my own simple Time class as I don't need locale specific stuff

Comment: Check the question now. I think I better phrased it